# How can .swf movies be made resizing themselves in accordance of different resolutions using HTML?

Tags: html

I made a table using HTML and inserted 6 .swf movies in a row with 1 .swf movie in one TD and I want them resizing themselves according to screen resolution as if all the .swf movies have width of 150px, it would need 900px to be displayed but if displayed on a screen of width 800px or less, an scroll bar will come under it which I don't want, I want them to be resizing so that there is no scroll bar, so how can I do it. Please help me.

Answer (score 0):

Try setting the width of each swf to a relative width, for instance

```
width="15%"
```

As opposed to:

```
width="150px"
```

Would it be possible to see your HTML at all?